# Copy a table in a Microsoft Word document, using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, ms-office

I have several hundred MS Word documents containing a single table in each. I need to copy the table, paste into Preview and save as jpeg. I can get Word to find the table, but cannot get the "copy object..." command to work. Suggestions welcome!

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    tell document 1
        count (tables)
        --  set firstTable to item 1 of tables — this does not work. Why?
        set table_list to tables
        set firstTable to item 1 of table_list
        tell firstTable
            allow page breaks
            -- allow page breaks (false) -- syntax error, () not allowed. Why?
            set allow page breaks to false -- This does not work either.
            allow page breaks
        end tell
        select firstTable -- this works! Now what?
        copy object firstTable --error -1708; doesnt understand "copy object"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: 'set firstTable…' fails because 'tables' isn't really what you should be asking. Try 'table 1', which will give you something like 'table 1 of document 1 of app Word'. Given that you have one table in each document, why do you want to work with it as a list?

Comment: Think of 'allow page breaks' as an adjective rather than a verb. It could be used like this: 'set allow page breaks to true'. I see that setting it failed but if you clear out the crud above it (e.g. the 'allow page breaks' line) then it should work.

Comment: ‘Set firstTable...’ does not fail. It works great. It is the ‘copy object xxx’ that fails. 

The first ‘allow page breaks’ returns the current state; the MS Word dictionary says the syntax is ‘allow page breaks (Boolean)’ but The compiler complains about the (). 

I was working with tableList in case I decided to process multiple tables in a document.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your comment then. The parentheses are not part of the syntax. They are part of the dictionary description, to let you know that the property will be a boolean. Try 'copy object selection' without the variable name. Ah, in your question, you specify a single table for each document. Perhaps you could edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified the example and was able to find a solution to the invalid "copy object xxx" command syntax. I still don't understand the the actual format for "copy object ..." in Word, but this works!

Script to select the first Table in an MS Word document and copy it to the Clipboard. Can be enhanced to read a folder of documents and process each one. Using list of tables can process multiple tables in a doc.

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
activate
    set firstTable to table 1 of active document
    select firstTable
    copy object selection
end tell
```

Comment: If you can find a copy of the 'word-2004-applescript-reference' document, it offers a bit of insight into the 'copy object' command. A 'selection' is an object, and hence this command can use it. You can also 'paste object selection' (along with other objects). It may seem like an old doc (and it is) but Microsoft made a great effort to implement applescript with that release, perhaps because they were not including VBA. So as far as I know, it's mostly still valid. There are corresponding Excel and Powerpoint reference docs as well.

Comment: Thanks! I found a copy and downloaded. And thanks to Darwin OS X for properly formatting my code example. I could not find info on how to do that. Maybe I am Search Impaired in my dotage.

Comment: I struggle with the whole Word/Excel object thing myself so having those docs really helps me. By format, do you mean so it appears as code on this site? If a line has 4 spaces in front of it then it is automatic. The block also needs to have an empty line above and below. But to make consistency easy, select your block of text and click the code button — '{ }'. One suggestion… if there isn't a specific requirement to use jpg, why not use png? Unless there is a photographic element to your table, jpg will typically introduce artefacts and won't look as good.